# Doctrine - replace items in one to many relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, for products and translations:

```
class ProductEntity
{
    /**
    * @Id
    * @var string
    * @Column(type="string", length=3)
    */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductTranslationEntity", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $translations;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /.../ getters and setters


    public function addTranslation(ProductTranslationEntity $productTranslation)
    {
        $this->translations->add($productTranslation);
    }

    public function clearTranslations()
    {
        $this->translations->clear();
    }
}
```

.

```
class ProductTranslationEntity
{
    /**
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductEntity", inversedBy="translations")
    * @JoinColumn(name="product_code", referencedColumnName="code", onDelete="CASCADE")
    * @Id
     */
    private $product;

    /**
    * @var string
    * @Column(type="string", name="language_code", length=5)
    * @Id 
    */
    protected $languageCode;

    /**
    * @var string
    * @Column(type="string", name="product_name", length=128)
    */
    protected $productName;

    /.../ getters and setters
}
```

I like to replace all translations with new ones, from array like that:

`['en' => ['name' => 'name_en'], 'de' => ['name' => 'name_de']];`

Because in this array I have set of all supported languages the bast way I can see is to remove all existing translations and put new ones:

```
$product // Existing product entity
$product->clearTranslations();
$this->entityManager->flush($product);

foreach ($translations as $code => $translation) {
    $t = new ProductTranslationEntity();
    $t->setProduct($product);
    $t->setLanguageCode($code);
    $t->setProductName($translation['name']);
    $this->entityManager->persist($t);
    $product->addTranslation($t);
}

$this->entityManager->flush($product);
```

This solution doesn't work because after first `$this->entityManager->flush($product);` there are still translations in database so i get error about duplicates.

What have I done wrong in my solution? Or maybe there is another way to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: So add `persist`? But really you should iterate about `Product`s translations and replace ones that already exist.

Answer (score 3):

As Doctrine documentation refers:

> Changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored.
>   Make sure to update both sides of a bidirectional association (or at
>   least the owning side, from Doctrine's point of view).

So to properly clear the translations of a product you should change the clearTranslations() function inside Product entity to:

```
public function clearTranslations()
{
    foreach ($this->translations as $translation) {
        $translation->setProduct(null);
    }
    $this->translations->clear();
}
```

so that you also update the owning side of the association before removal.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe a bit overload but still it does not use extra requests to database:

```
$current_translations = $product->getTranslations();
foreach ($translations as $code => $translation) {
    $translation_found = false;
    foreach ($current_translations as $current_translation) {
        if ($current_translation->getLanguageCode() === $code) {
            // you've found the translation - replace value
            $current_translation->setProductName($translation['name']);
            $translation_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$translation_found) {
        // translation with such code not found - add a new one
        $t = new ProductTranslationEntity();
        $t->setProduct($product);
        $t->setLanguageCode($code);
        $t->setProductName($translation['name']);
        $this->entityManager->persist($t);
        $product->addTranslation($t);
    }
}
$this->entityManager->persist($product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use orphanRemoval=true:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductTranslationEntity", mappedBy="product", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $translations;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Adding a little bit of explanation as to what this will do and how it works will make this a better answer.